# Why can't I scroll page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget ListView but still I can't scroll through the pictures. I tried replacing Column but still it didn't work for me. Is there any other option?

Also, when I wrap StreamBuilder with SingleChildScrollView I get following error:

RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#9fda5 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Here is my code:

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('userImage')
              //  .orderBy('date', descending: true)
              .where('name', isEqualTo: name)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            return ListView(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('$name'),
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.open_in_new,
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        onPressed: logout)
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/like.png',
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/donate.png',
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.offline_bolt,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      size: 36,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 100, right: 100, top: 50, bottom: 50),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'order pics & clips',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(name);
                      print(email);
                      print(account);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          ProfilePost(
                              snapshot.data.documents[i]['url'],
                              snapshot.data.documents[i]['likes'].toString(),
                              snapshot.data.documents[i]['donations']
                                  .toString())
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ],
            );
          }),
```

Comment: are you talking about listview or listview.builder? You have two lists

Comment: I would suggest you to wrap List as Container or SizedBox and give it a height of something and then check?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `shrinkWrap: true` property on the `ListView()` and `ListView.builder()`  widgets so that the total size (height) of the listview is the sum of the heights of the children.